# Flutter run terminal is showing Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, build.gradle, launch

**Flutter is showing this in terminal please can anyone help.**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

*below is  the code report from the VScode terminal*

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\Practice\Mobile\Flutter\hello_flutter> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
                                                                            
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type DefaultUserHomeScopedCompileCaches using UserHomeScopeServices.createCompileCaches().
    
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        12.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**I have tried all possible solutions, i would be glad to be unblocked of this issue thanks.**

I also have a screenshot for more clarity, pls check.
[image]

Comment: run `flutter run -v`

Comment: @neuromancer i will check that now, thanks.

Comment: @neuromancer i have done that and after a long log it still gave me **`Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`**  The same problem i have been running into.

Comment: yeah but with more information, please post the details

Comment: @neuromancer okay, i will